# While loop still looping

Tags: python, while-loop

I need to have 'F' or 'M' as input from the user. So there is my code :

```
a = input("")
while a != 'F' or a != 'M':
    a = input("")
```

But it still looping even if the user enter 'M' or 'F' or anything else.
so I've tried this :

```
genre = input("")
while genre != 'F':
    genre = input("")
```

And it works..
I just need to have 'M' OR 'F', could someone help me with this?

Thank's in advance

Comment: Your condition is **always true**, it doesn't matter what the value of `a` is. *At least one* of your two `!=` conditions will be true (`a` can't  be set to `F` and `M` at the same time), and `or` on `True or False` or `False or True` or `True or True` will always be true. You want to use `and`, you want both tests to be true *together, at the same time*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need `and` instead of `or`

```
while a != 'F' and a != 'M'
```

because `a` can't be equal to two things at a time. As it is now, if `a=='M'`, then `a != 'F'`, so the loop continues (the same for the reverse values). So, the loop will never end.

Comment: thank's a lot , but i've now this problem :

Comment: danger = input("")                                                                                              while type(danger) != int:
        danger = input("")                                                                                                                        it still looping whatever i put the input

Comment: what you get from `input` is always a string. so you need to convert it to `int`.

Comment: like this ? :  danger = int(input("")                                                                                        but if i enter a string i will have an error because not the right type and i need to accept this error of wrong type without except. I need to loop while i have not an int

Comment: you can't do that in `while` alone. you can to use `try/except` to convert it to integer

Answer (score 1):

one of  `a != 'F' or a != 'M'` will always be `True`. try this:

```
while a not in 'FM':
    ...
```

although this will also accept `FM`; the better way is to use:

```
while a not in set('FM'):
    ...
```

Comment: File "<input>", line 2
    while a not in 'FM'
                          ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: that is not enough information to help. what *exacly* caused the syntax error? what are the lines before and after the `while`? is the indentation correct?

Comment: i've tried this in the console

Comment: @FatihAkman: You missed the `:` at the end.